# Oracle impdb with error ORA-31693 ORA-02354 ORA-24329

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

I'm using impdp for import a schema from another server to a new server and get an error as below.
I got this error with all tables using NVARCHAR2.
Tables that do not use NVARCHAR2 are still imported normally

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "XXXXX"."AuditLogActions" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-24329: invalid character set identifier
ORA-31693: Table data object "XXXXX"."AuditLogs" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-24329: invalid character set identifier
```

Comment: What are the versions of both databases? Also, what is the output of `select userenv('language') from dual;` and `Select * FROM nls_database_parameters Where parameter IN ('NLS_LANGUAGE','NLS_TERRITORY','NLS_CHARACTERSET')`?

Comment: I found the cause of the error and fix it with commands: SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup restrict;
SQL> alter system enable restricted session;
SQL> alter system set job_queue_processes = 0;
SQL> alter system set aq_tm_processes = 0;
SQL> alter database National Character Set internal_use utf8;
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup;

Comment: You should put that comment as an answer (and explain why it solved the problem).